# Why must loop to delete rows be run several times to remove all rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data that looks like this:

```
00 some data here...
00 some data here...
00 some data here...
00 some data here...
Other data I want to remove
Other data I want to remove
Other data I want to remove
Other data I want to remove
00I also want to remove
002 some other data I want to remove
003 remove this as well
```

I want to remove all the rows that do not start with 00 (space). My function removes some of them only.

**Observation:** My code will delete a few rows at each run, if I run this 4-5 times, it will eventually remove all of them.

```
Sub ProcessRemittance()
    Dim remitDate, remitNumber, myString, tempString As String
    Dim myRange, cell As Range
    Dim StringArray As Variant

    Set myRange = Range("A1:A500")

    ' Remove all the empty rows in the worksheet
    myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    ' Clean up every row does not belong to invoices
    For Each cell In myRange
        myString = Left(cell.Value, 3)

        If myString <> "00 " Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Try starting at the bottom of the range and move to the top. It means that you cannot use a for each loop. But the problem may lie in the fact that Excel loses its hold on the range when you start deleting rows above the next row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your moving forward through the rows - if you delete row 4 then row 5 becomes row 4 and the code will jump to the new row 5 - which is in fact row 6.

Hope that made sense. :)

The solution will be to use a For Next Loop - stepping backwards and not a For Each Loop.

Also - the special cells delete row will fail if there's no blank rows.

I've updated your code to include these changes:

```
Sub ProcessRemittance()

    'Each variable needs a type - otherwise they're variants.
    Dim remitDate As Date, remitNumber As Long, myString As String, tempString As String
    Dim myRange As Range, cell As Range
    Dim StringArray As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

        For x = 10 To 1 Step -1
            myString = Left(.Cells(x, 1), 3)

            If myString <> "00 " Then
                .Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next x

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004 'No cells were found (occurs if SpecialCells returns nothing).
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ProcessRemittance."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I see! Let me try to re-write this with a For Next loop!